# From UTC to date vector

Tags: matlab, datetime, date, utc

I have a set of date expressed in form of `2010-07-31T23:01:57Z`. I need to transform it into  vector. I could do this as `datavec(mydate)` it will transform automatically the string into vector, but this function doesn't accept UTC string date. So I have rudely resolved in this way:

```
a = `2010-07-31T23:01:57Z`; %UTC date format
a(20) = '';                 %remove Z
a(11) = ' ';                %replace T with a space 
a = datavec(a);             % [2010, 7, 31, 23, 1, 57]
```

In this way `a` is a datevector and I can use `etime(T1, T0)` to compute time difference between `T1` and `T0`. Is this the unique way or I can do something stylish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc suggests, all you have to do is 'help' MATLAB a bit by specifying the data format.

```
datevec('2010-07-31T23:01:57Z','yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS')
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

use the `fieldSpecIn` part of the `datevec()` call.  Read all about it here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html#bspgc4m-1

Except for the TZ spec at the end of your string and the -'s and :'s, yours is identical to the standard ISO 8601 format.  You can either modify yours, or create your own spec string.

Please note that Matlab time has no concept of time zone.  You must keep track of that yourself.

Comment: Update - matlab datenums have no concept of TZ - but the new datetime type does: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, you could specify the format of the expected date strings to functions like [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html) and [DATENUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html). Example:

```
%# set of dates and an initial date
T0 = '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z';
T = repmat({'2010-07-31T23:01:57Z'}, [10 1]);   %# cell array

%# format of datetime
frmt = 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS';

%# convert to serial date numbers, and compute difference between all T and T0
n = datenum(T,frmt);
n0 = datenum(T0,frmt);
tdiff = bsxfun(@minus, n, n0);
```

Alternatively, if you have an unusual date format, you can always split and parse it yourself with functions like [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html):

```
vec = zeros(numel(T),6);
for i=1:numel(T)
    C = textscan(T{i}, '%f', 'Delimiter',['-' ':' 'T' 'Z']);
    vec(i,:) = C{1};
end
n = datenum(vec);
```

Note that in both cases, you can convert back serial times to date strings with the [DATESTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html) function.